# fetching data from government agencies

Tags: web-services

We have 3 (maybe more in the future) agencies, each updating the price list of a certain product on a weekly basis, something like this:

- agency A updating product-1

- agency B updating product-2

- agency C updating product-3

I am tasked with the job of creating a way to import those information write the retrieved data into my mysql database  before displaying it on our site.

I have heard about web services but am not sure if this is the right way to do it. What do the 3 agencies need to do (this has never been done before on their part) before I am able retrieve their data ?

Please advise. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Web services are a way to let computers interact with other computers, usually for fetching data. The data you get back from web services are often in XML or JSON format, therefore they are quite easy to parse in any language. So this would surely be a viable way.
 Nonetheless, nowadays governmental authorities share data through [Linked Data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_data) which allow more sophisticated queries.
Anyway, it all depends on the agencies you want to fetch data from. They have to define the protocol and set up the sharing data infrastructure.